# Should subjective example questions be marked CW?

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, area-51, subjective

Marking example questions as community wiki makes the on-/off-topic decision for close-to-subjective questions easier.

Should subjective example questions allow for a community wiki indication?

Comment: Oh, boy! The great subjective controversy leaks to area 51!

Comment: +1 because it had to be asked, even though I [disagree](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52164/should-subjective-example-questions-be-marked-cw/52170#52170).

Comment: @rosinate better right from the beginning so it's in the faq soon...

Comment: @The Cat thanks for the edit, sounds better now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subjective != community wiki.

Questions are voted on-topic or off-topic no matter if they should be CW or not. Subjective questions should be off-topic, CW or not.

Comment: *Discussion* questions should be discouraged, and all of those are subjective.  Non-discussion subjective questions can be appropriate.  (There are very, very few of those, however.)

Answer (score 4):

Whether a question is on-topic or not isn't determined by whether it's community wiki.

I was initially confused about how things work, however, as "what is the best X?" is clearly on-topic for an "Xoverflow" proposal, even though it would/should be closed and discouraged.  I now interpret A51's "is it on-topic?" as "**do we want it on this site?**" or "**is it appropriate?**"