# Distinguish good CW questions from normal questions in proposals?

Tags: discussion, area-51, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should subjective example questions be marked CW?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52164/should-subjective-example-questions-be-marked-cw)

Currently, there are three possible responses to a question in a proposal:

- Good on-topic example
- Good off-topic example
- Not a good example

What about questions that would make good community-wiki questions?  For example: [What coffee shops should I visit in {{city}}?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4501/coffee/9661#9661)

If that question were on the site and made community-wiki, it could be a quite useful resource for the community. People post their coffee shops, others vote, and the upvotes give a prioritized list of places to visit.  It is not core to the business of asking and answering questions about the fine craft of making and enjoying coffee, but would be an excellent auxiliary resource forthe community.

So, my question gets down to two points:

- Are good community-wiki questions "good examples of on-topic questions" or "not good examples"?  I think making them good examples of off-topic questions is definitely not the way to go.
- Should there be a more nuanced way of handling community wiki subjects?  What should that look like?

**EDIT**: Very similar, if not identical, to [Should subjective example questions be marked CW?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52164/should-subjective-example-questions-be-marked-cw)

Comment: Given that my answer is identical to the one's on that question, I'd agree that it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Community Wiki should not be seen as synonymous with Poll or as a means of allowing subjective questions.

Ultimately all questions and answers will become CW if they are edited enough.

So what I'm saying is a question should be a good question regardless of whether it's Community Wiki or not.